# Implementing Order of Operations (PEMDAS) in a Delphi calculator

Tags: delphi

I'm currently learning Delphi and I am practicing by creating a calculator to get used to the language. So far everything works good, but I'm struggling with implementing the order of operations, also known as "point before dash" or PEDMAS (Parenthesis, Exponents, Multiplication and Division, Addition and Subtraction).

To read my operands (when more than two operands are involved), I'm using `TStringList` and a different variable for my operators. The user-entered equation is read from a `TMemo` into the `TStringList`, and the memo is set to an empty string.

To illustrate what I mean, consider the equation `5 + 2 * 6`. According to the order of operations, multiplication should be done before addition, resulting in `5 + 12`, which equals 17.

I considered some solutions such as putting tokens/flags in my `TStringList` or doing everything recursively, but I have't figured out how to effectively implement these ideas. Is there any other good solution? Also asking for a pseudocode by any chance?

```pascal
unit f_HelloWorld;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Math;

  type
  TformCalculator = class(TForm)
    mOutput: TMemo;
    buttonClear: TButton;
    buttonDivision: TButton;
    buttonMultiply: TButton;
    buttonDelete: TButton;
    buttonMinus: TButton;
    buttonPlus: TButton;
    buttonOperand1: TButton;
    buttonOperand2: TButton;
    buttonOperand3: TButton;
    buttonOperand4: TButton;
    buttonOperand5: TButton;
    buttonOperand6: TButton;
    buttonOperand7: TButton;
    buttonOperand8: TButton;
    buttonOperand9: TButton;
    buttonModulo: TButton;
    buttonOperand0: TButton;
    buttonComma: TButton;
    buttonEqual: TButton;
    buttonPlusMinus: TButton;
    buttonPowerOfTen: TButton;
    buttonSecondPage: TButton;
    buttonSquared: TButton;
    buttonPoweredBy: TButton;
    buttonSquareRoot: TButton;
    buttonLog: TButton;
    buttonNaturalLogarithm: TButton;
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonClearClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonCommaClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonDivisionClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonEqualClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonLogClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonMinusClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonModuloClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonNaturalLogarithmClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonNumberClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonPlusClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonPlusMinusClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonPoweredByClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonSquaredClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonSecondPageClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonPowerOfTenClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonPowerThreeClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonSquareRootClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonThirdSquareRootClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonPowerOfTwoClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure buttonEulerPowerClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    fOperators: Char;
    fOperandList: TStringList;                                  
    fIsToggle: Boolean;
  public

  end;

var
  formCalculator: TformCalculator;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TformCalculator.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(fOperandList);
end;

procedure TformCalculator.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fOperandList := TStringList.Create;
  fIsToggle := false;
  mOutput.Text := '0';
end;

procedure TformCalculator.buttonClearClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mOutput.Text := '0';
end;

procedure TformCalculator.buttonCommaClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Pos(',', mOutput.Text) <> 0) then
    Exit
  else
    mOutput.Text := mOutput.Text + buttonComma.Caption;
end;

procedure TformCalculator.buttonDeleteClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mOutput.Text := Copy(mOutput.Text, 1, Length(mOutput.Text) - 1);
  if mOutput.Text = '' then
  begin
    mOutput.Text := '0';
  end;
  
end;

// Division ÷
procedure TformCalculator.buttonDivisionClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fOperandList.add(mOutput.Text);
  fOperators := '/';
  mOutput.Text := '';
end;

// =
procedure TformCalculator.buttonEqualClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dAnswer: Double;
  iterator: Integer;
  iterator2: Integer;
begin
  fOperandList.Add(mOutput.Text);

  dAnswer := 0;
  for iterator := 0 to fOperandList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if fOperators = '+' then
      dAnswer := dAnswer + StrToFloat(fOperandList[iterator]);

    if fOperators = '-' then
      dAnswer := dAnswer - StrToFloat(fOperandList[iterator]);

    if fOperators = '*' then
      dAnswer := dAnswer * StrToFloat(fOperandList[iterator]);

    if fOperators = '/' then
      dAnswer := dAnswer / StrToFloat(fOperandList[iterator]);

    if fOperators = '%' then
      if fOperandList.IndexOf(',') or fOperandList.IndexOf('.') >= 0 then 
        mOutput.Text := 'Keine Gleitkommazahlen bei Modulo!'
      else if (iterator = 0) then     
        dAnswer := StrToInt(fOperandList[iterator])
      else 
        dAnswer := Trunc(dAnswer) mod StrToInt(fOperandList[iterator]);

    if fOperators = 'x' then
      dAnswer := dAnswer + Power(dAnswer, StrToInt(fOperandList[iterator]));
        

  end;
      mOutput.Text := FloatToStr(dAnswer);
  fOperandList.clear;
end;

// Log / Logarithm
procedure TformCalculator.buttonLogClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mOutput.Text := FloatToStr(Log10(StrToFloat(mOutput.Text)));
end;

// - Minus
procedure TformCalculator.buttonMinusClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fOperandList.add(mOutput.Text);
  fOperators := '-';
  mOutput.Text := '';
end;

// % / Modulo
procedure TformCalculator.buttonModuloClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fOperandList.add(mOutput.Text);
  fOperators := '%';
  mOutput.Text := '';
end;

// ln / Natural Logarithm
procedure TformCalculator.buttonNaturalLogarithmClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mOutput.Text := FloatToStr(Ln(StrToInt(mOutput.Text)));
end;

{ TForm1 }

// Number on Click
procedure TformCalculator.buttonNumberClick(Sender: TObject);
var pressedButton: TButton;
begin
  pressedButton := Sender as TButton;
  if mOutput.Text = '0' then
  begin
    mOutput.Text := pressedButton.Caption;
  end
  else
    mOutput.Text := mOutput.Text + pressedButton.Caption;
end;

// +
procedure TformCalculator.buttonPlusClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fOperandList.add(mOutput.Text);
  fOperators := '+';
  mOutput.Text := '';
end;

// -+ / Prefix
procedure TformCalculator.buttonPlusMinusClick(Sender: TObject);
var q: real;
begin
  q := StrToFloat(mOutput.Text);

  mOutput.Text := FloatToStr(-1 * q);
end;

// x^y
procedure TformCalculator.buttonPoweredByClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iterator: Integer;
  result: Double;
begin
  fOperandList.add(mOutput.Text);
  fOperators := 'x'; // x is a placeholder
  mOutput.Text := '';
end;

// 2nd / Second Page
procedure TformCalculator.buttonSecondPageClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not (fIsToggle) then
  begin
    buttonSquared.Caption := 'x^3';
    buttonSquared.OnClick := buttonPowerThreeClick;

    buttonSquareRoot.Caption := '3rd Sqrt';
    buttonSquareRoot.OnClick := buttonThirdSquareRootClick;

    buttonPowerOfTen.Caption := '2^x';
    buttonPowerOfTen.OnClick := buttonPowerOfTwoClick;

    buttonNaturalLogarithm.Caption := 'e^x';
    buttonNaturalLogarithm.OnClick := buttonEulerPowerClick;

    mOutput.Text := '';

    fIsToggle := true;
  end
  else
  begin
    buttonSquared.Caption := 'x^2';
    buttonSquared.OnClick := buttonSquaredClick;
    mOutput.Text := '';

    buttonSquareRoot.Caption := 'Sqrt';
    buttonSquareRoot.OnClick := buttonSquareRootClick;

    buttonPowerOfTen.Caption := '10^x';
    buttonPowerOfTen.OnClick := buttonPowerOfTenClick;

    buttonNaturalLogarithm.Caption := 'ln';
    buttonNaturalLogarithm.OnClick := buttonNaturalLogarithmClick;
    
    fIsToggle := false;
  end;
end;

// x^2
procedure TformCalculator.buttonSquaredClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mOutput.Text := FloatToStr(StrToFloat(mOutput.Text) * StrToFloat(mOutput.Text));
end;

// x^3
procedure TformCalculator.buttonPowerThreeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mOutput.Text := FloatToStr(StrToFloat(mOutput.Text) * StrToFloat(mOutput.Text) * StrToFloat(mOutput.Text));
end;

// 3. Wurzel von x
procedure TformCalculator.buttonThirdSquareRootClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mOutput.Text := FloatToStr(Exp((1/3) * Ln(StrToFloat(mOutput.Text))));
end;

// Sqrt(x)
procedure TformCalculator.buttonSquareRootClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    mOutput.Lines.Text := FloatToStr(Sqrt(StrToFloat(mOutput.Text)));
end;

// 10^x
procedure TformCalculator.buttonPowerOfTenClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iterator: Integer;
  result: Double;
begin
  result := 1;
  for iterator := 0 to StrToInt(mOutput.Text) - 1 do
    result := 10 * result;

  mOutput.Text := FloatToStr(result);
end;

// 2^x
procedure TformCalculator.buttonPowerOfTwoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iterator: Integer;
  result: Double;
begin
  result := 1;
  for iterator := 0 to StrToInt(mOutput.Text) - 1 do
    result := 2 * result;

  mOutput.Text := FloatToStr(result);
end;

// e^x
procedure TformCalculator.buttonEulerPowerClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iterator: Integer;
  result: Double;
  temp: Double;
begin
  result := 1;
  for iterator := 0 to StrToInt(mOutput.Text) - 1 do
    result := Exp(1) * result;
  mOutput.Text := FloatToStr(result);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Please clarify for the uneducated ones: what is *Point-Before-Dash Calculation*? Please also provide the code you have sofar.

Comment: ...and power before both of them. Just to complete the task.

Comment: Thanks @nahic *Order of operations* is another expression.

Comment: the problem with your design is that while you are storing your operands in a string list so you can access to them later in same order as they were added you are not doing same for operators. Since you have declared `FOperators` as `Char` it gets replaced every time you click on any of your operator buttons.  You also need to store your operators in some kind of array or string.  Then you loop trough your operators calculating multiplication and division first and after that loop again performing addition and subtraction.

Comment: Read the code of an actual expression parser. Why start from ground zero?

Comment: It's nice that you're trying to learn Object Pascal, but this isn't a programming problem at this point; it's only confusing you. You don't seem to understand what you need to do to parse a math expression. Try solving it in a language you're more familiar with first in this case. Get some sticky notes and write numbers and math symbols on them, them make expressions, and work out an algorithm for pushing and popping them to/from a stack and applying the operators. That's what @DavidHeffernan is suggesting. Figure out the problem you're trying to solve first, then figure out how to code it.